# Bash script mv and restore to original location with log

Tags: bash

I am about as new to bash scripts as it gets, so probably quite the stupid question, but here it goes.
The idea is as follows: save *basename* of a file in a log--> move file--> use log to move back to original location.

```
basename $filename >> /directory/log
mv $filename /directory
```

So far so good, but I am quite confused as to how to use that log file to get file back. Is *basename* even the right thing to use? Idea I had was using *grep* to find filename in the log, but how do I go about getting that output at the end of *mv* ?

```
mv $filename ???
```

Am I on the right track? Screwing up something very basic?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please elaborate. you can use the `basename` as you described.

Comment: Well, is using _grep_ valid in this case and if so, how do i get that output to work with _mv_? If not, what options are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take the file `httpd.conf` as an example, it's location is in directory `/etc/httpd/conf/`

```
$ ls /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

The command `basename` strips the path of the file and just returns the filename *(and extension)*.

```
$ basename /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
httpd.conf
```

So when you do:

```
basename $filename >> /directory/log
```

You are creating a log file that contains only file names, you will not be able to use `/directory/log` to move the file back to it's original location because you stripped that information with the `basename` command.

You would want to do something like this:

```
echo $filename >> /directory/log
mv $filename /directory
```

So that now `/directory` is the new location of the file and `/directory/log` contains the original location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a string from a file and use it in some command, then `grep` would work

```
mv $filename `grep <your-grep-pattern> <you-logfile>`
```

This will do the appropriate action, given the logfile contains the correct data for the match.

Answer (score 0):

to the something like this ?

```
#set a variable saving the filename but not path of a file. 
MY_FILENAME=$(basename $filename)
echo $MY_FILENAME >> /directory/log
mv $MY_FILENAME /diectroy/.

# DO STUFF HERE
# to your file here 

#Move the file to the PWD. 
mv /directory/${MY_FILENAME} .
unset $MY_FILENAME 
      #unseting variable when you are done with them, while not always 
      #not always necessary, i think is a good practice.
```

Conversely if you want to move the file back to the orgianl location rather then the PWD the second mv statement would look like this.

```
mv /directory/${MY_FILENAME} $filename
```

Further if due to some scoping issue, you dont have thate local var available when you do the move back and REALLY need to read it from a file youo should do it something like this :

```
 #set a variable saving the filename but not path of a file. 
MY_FILENAME=$(basename $filename)
echo "MY_FILENAME = " $MY_FILENAME >> /directory/log
# I'm tagging my var with some useful title so it is easier to grep for it later
mv $MY_FILENAME /diectroy/.

# DO STUFF HERE
# to your file here 

#Ive somehow forgotten my local var and need to get it back.
MY_FILENAME=$(cat /directory/log | grep "^MY_FILENAME = .*" | awk '{print $3}');
#inside the $() a cat the file to read it
# grep on "^MY_FILENAME = .*" to get the line that starts with the header i gave my filename
# and awk to give me the third token ( I always use awk over cut out of preference, cut would work also. 
# This assumes you only write ONE filename to the log, 
# writing more makes things more complicated

mv /directory/${MY_FILENAME} $filename
unset $MY_FILENAME
```